# Metric retention is 6 weeks. Can I keep my metrics more time?

Tags: logging, google-bigquery, monitoring, metrics, stackdriver

Is there a way to backup my metrics and/or logs for example to BigQuery or something. I want to have more than 6 weeks retention for my metrics.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to export Stackdriver logs into BigQuery ? If yes - the following documentation should have all the details: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2

Comment: I'm attempting to export custom Stackdriver Metrics to a datastore that's more conducive to creating dashboards for external sharing (because StackDriver's charts are quite limited in functionality and can't be shared with granular access control).

BigQuery + DataStudio seem to be Google's standard tools for creating and sharing data-driven dashboards. However while setting up a sink to export Stackdriver **Logs** to BigQuery is trivial and well-documented I can't find any standard, documented way to sink Stackdriver (custom) **Metrics** to long-term storage (BigQuery or otherwise).